Why does parquet file with snappy compression contains raw strings?
I'm using apache spark to write parquet files with snappy compression enabled. parquet schema is quite big, 300+ columns, numbers, string, raw bytes.
All output files at HDFS have snappy.parquet suffix.
I did hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://cluster/dir/file.snappy.parquet and I can see raw strings in output, some strings are even repeated multiple times in a row. Is it by design or I have some issues with compression settings?
These strings are columns values, not headers or any metadata related stuff.

You can probably use parquet-cli or parquet-tools (depending on your parquet version) to validate compression methods used in your files. You can also really cat, scan or head your data with it.

Snappy is not designed for good compression. It is designed for fast compression. It will not always catch where it could have matched a string.
